# How do you find the group that has X, Y, Z members?

Tags: sql

In a one-to-many relationship, let's say a `Group` has many `Members`, and I have 3 members. How do I find the group that they are apart of?

```
users
-------
1 Alice
2 Bob
3 Charlie
4 Doug


groups
-------
1 Pokemon Club
2 Bitcoin Club
3 Sunday Martinis
4 WSB

members
-------
group_id, user_id
1, 1
1, 2
1, 3
2, 1
2, 2
2, 3
3, 1
3, 2
3, 4
4, 3
```

I want to craft a SQL where I would get Group 1 and 2 given user 1, 2 and 3. How do I do this?

Comment: Why not group 2? (Also has user 1, 2 and 3 as members.)

Comment: @jarlh Oops, typo, but good point. I would want both. Updating my post.

Comment: GROUP BY, HAVING, COUNT DISTINCT.

Comment: @jarlh Put your answer in :)

Comment: What if one group had 1, 2, 3, and 4?  Would you still want it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help you,

```
select group_id from members 
where user_id in(1,2,3)
group by group_id
having count(group_id) = 3;
```

Comment: No need to do select distinct here, the group by returns no duplicates.